# Use Google Cloud Workflows + Cloud Scheduler to execute single Dataform Sqlx Transformation

Tags: google-cloud-platform, yaml, google-cloud-scheduler, dataform, google-workflows

I've been tasked to POC using Google Cloud Workflows and Cloud Scheduler to execute transformations in my Dataform repo.

I followed the docs [here](https://cloud.google.com/dataform/docs/schedule-executions-workflows) and used the provided YAML source code but it executed every .sqlx file in my repository.

How do I alter this to make it execute a single chosen Dataform transformation.

This is the code I used:

```
main:
steps:
- init:
    assign:
    - repository: projects/PROJECT_ID/locations/REPOSITORY_LOCATION/repositories/REPOSITORY_ID
- createCompilationResult:
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: ${"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + repository + "/compilationResults"}
        auth:
            type: OAuth2
        body:
            gitCommitish: GIT_COMMITISH
    result: compilationResult
- createWorkflowInvocation:
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: ${"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + repository + "/workflowInvocations"}
        auth:
            type: OAuth2
        body:
            compilationResult: ${compilationResult.body.name}
    result: workflowInvocation
- complete:
    return: ${workflowInvocation.body.name}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
- createWorkflowInvocation:
    call: http.post
    args:
        url: ${"https://dataform.googleapis.com/v1beta1/" + repository + "/workflowInvocations"}
        auth:
            type: OAuth2
        body:
            compilationResult: ${compilationResult.body.name}
    result: workflowInvocation
```

An additional `includes` argument is present in the `workflowDefinition` part of the example code. This parameter specifies that the workflow execution will include any SQL files in the specified path that have the `.sqlx` extension.

Remove the `includes` option and set the `path` parameter to the location of the particular Dataform transformation file you wish to run in order to execute only that SQL file.

Comment: there is no workflowDefinition part of the example code. At least not in the example code I've shared the link to in my original post. What are you referring to?